# Filter dataframe: certain column contains ALL substrings of a certain list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given...

```
    target_column
1   XXX   
2   YYY
3   XXX YYY
4   ZZZ 
5   PPP XXX
```

When I want to filter a dataframe by a column that contains ANY of the items of a list, this is what I do:

```
filters = ["YYY", "XXX"]
mask = data["target_column"].str.contains("|".join(filters))
data.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```
    target_column
1   XXX   
2   YYY
3   XXX YYY
5   PPP XXX
```

When I want to filter a dataframe by a column that contains ALL items of a list, this is what I do:

```
mask = (data["target_column"].str.contains("YYY")) & \
       (data["target_column"].str.contains("XXX"))
data.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```
    target_column
3   XXX YYY
```

This last one might become worky if you have many items.

So my question is: is there a way closer to the first one where I can save the keywords/filters into a list and more easily filter the dataframe per rows that contains ALL items of that list?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can pass regex to `str.contains` you could do:

```
filters = ["YYY", "XXX"]
mask = data["target_column"].str.contains(f'(?=.*{filters[0]})(?=.*{filters[1]})')
```

Output `data.loc[mask]`:

|  | target_column |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | XXX YYY |

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df.loc[df['target_column'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').loc[:,filters].gt(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Here is another way using `set`

```
df.loc[df['target_column'].str.split().map(set).eq(set(filters))]
```